# How to change a TextView text and color after a timer starts and after it ends

Tags: android, button, timer, textview, counter

i am new to app development and i am currently trying to make a counter app.
i have set up the buttons so that the text changes with the button pressed.
although, i am trying to make the text display the adding or subtracting value and then show the total number afterwards.

For example, my counter starts at 20;
if i press the add button i want the textview text to change to +1, +2, +3 and so on for however many times the button is pressed within a time of 2 seconds. After 2 second i want the textview to show the total again. So if i pressed it 3 times, after 2 seconds on the 3rd press i want it to display "23" and not "+3" anymore.
Then, if i pressed the minus button just once the textview will display "-1" and then after 2 seconds change to "22", etc. I also want the text color to change to green when the add button is pressed, red when the minus is pressed and white when displaying the total or at default.

Here is my code so far, i am probably off by a mile but i would really like some help to be shown in the right direction.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Thread timer;
    TextView lifepointsP1;
    ImageButton p1AddL, p1SubL;

    int counter1;
    int count;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        counter1 = 20;
        count = 0;
        lifepointsP1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvP1LP);
        p1AddL = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bP1add);
        p1SubL = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bP1take);

        //the timer

        timer = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    synchronized(this){
                        wait(2000);
                    }
                } catch(InterruptedException e){  
                       e.printStackTrace();
                }
                count = 0;
                lifepointsP1.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
            }
        };

        p1AddL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        //the buttons

            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter1++;
                count++;
                if (count == 0) {
                    if (counter1 >= 9|counter1 <= -1) {
                        lifepointsP1.setText("" + counter1);
                    } else {
                        lifepointsP1.setText("0" + counter1);
                    }
                } else if (count > 0) {
                    lifepointsP1.setText("+" + count);
                    lifepointsP1.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 188, 0));
                }
            }
        });

        p1SubL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter1--;
                count--;
                if (count == 0) {
                    if (counter1 >= 9|counter1 <= -1) {
                        lifepointsP1.setText("" + counter1);
                    } else {
                        lifepointsP1.setText("0" + counter1);
                    }
                } else if (count < 0) {
                    lifepointsP1.setText("-" + count);
                    lifepointsP1.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 214, 0, 0));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //the counter reset if pressed

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt) {

        if(evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            synchronized(timer){
                timer.start();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Ive also set it up so that if the button is pressed while the timer is counting it will reset the count to start again.
Thanks in advanced for any help, its really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [`CountdownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

You can implement your logic in the `onFinish()` method then.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with Handler class

> A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects
>   associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is
>   associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When
>   you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of
>   the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver
>   messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they
>   come out of the message queue.
>
> There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and
>   runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and (2) to
>   enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.

```
public int i = 0;
```

Then:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(i != 20) { 
                text.append(" " + i);
                i++;
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            } else {
                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                text.append(" Stopped");
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```